# Combine rows altogether with the date in month

Tags: php, mysql

I failed to combine the rows follow the date in months. I did query as below however the result is not as I expected to be.

I used myphpadmin to do the sql there as i save my database i it. I tried to use pivot for php however it shows failed.

```
SELECT MONTH(Date) as Months ,Code='J01' as A,Code='J02' as B,Code='J03' as C, COUNT(Date) as Total FROM Table_a WHERE Code IN('J01','J02','J03') AND YEAR(Date)='2018' GROUP BY Code, Months
```

As the result from above query is below;

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Months |   A    |        B        |    C       | Total 
-------------------------------------------------------
1          1             0             0          12
2          1             0             0          15
3          1             0             0          10
4          1             0             0           4
5          1             0             0          11
6          1             0             0           8
7          1             0             0           3
8          1             0             0          10
9          1             0             0          15
10         1             0             0          12
11         1             0             0          10
12         1             0             0          25
8          0             1             0           5
9          0             1             0          10
10         0             1             0          15
11         0             1             0          20
12         0             1             0          25
8          0             0             1          10
9          0             0             1           9
10         0             0             1          13
11         0             0             1          17
12         0             0             1          18
--------------------------------------------------------
```

i expect it to be like below:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Months |   A    |        B        |    C       | Total  
-------------------------------------------------------
1         12             0             0          12
2         15             0             0          15
3         10             0             0          10
4          4             0             0           4
5         11             0             0          11
6          8             0             0           8
7          3             0             0           3
8         10             5            10          25
9         15            10             9          34
10        12            15            13          50
11        10            20            17          47
12        25            25            18          68
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Search for mysql pivot or mysql conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be grouping by `Code`, and you need to `SUM` the occurrences of each `Code` type. Try this:

```
SELECT MONTH(Date) as Months,
       SUM(Code='J01') as A,
       SUM(Code='J02') as B,
       SUM(Code='J03') as C, 
       COUNT(Date) as Total
FROM Table_a 
WHERE Code IN('J01','J02','J03') AND YEAR(Date)='2018' 
GROUP BY Months
```